# Create custom glyphs and sprites to use with mapbox

Tags: mapbox

I would like to self-host my vector maps. I am using some custom fonts and also some custom icons.

When I create a style in Mapbox Studio and export it later I will have the following two lines inside my styles file:

```
"sprite": "mapbox://sprites/<user>/<token>/<token>",
"glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/<user>/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
```

My question now is how do I create those files myself? I have a folder containing my `.svg` and my `.ttf` files. But how do I now get them into the format I need?

I tried https://github.com/openmaptiles/fonts for the glyphs part, but can't get that running. And then I found https://github.com/mapbox/glyph-pbf-composite but don't understand how it should work.

Answer (score 5):

The easy method is to:

1. add the svgs and fonts into a MapBox style
2. open a test map in a browser
3. inspect the Network calls with the browser's dev tools. Find the calls to get the sprite and glyph files
4. open those URLs in a new browser tab and save the files that are downloaded

Otherwise if you want to generate the files without using MapBox Studio:

You'll use two utilities as outline in the instructions from https://openmaptiles.org/docs/style/mapbox-gl-style-spec/

**Sprite file generation**: SpriteZero CLI - https://github.com/mapbox/spritezero-cli

**Glyph file generation**: genfontgl - https://github.com/openmaptiles/genfontgl

Finally, when defining the path to the files you do still need the tokens in the glyphs path even though you aren't using them. So something like

```
"glyphs": "/data/myfonts.pbf?{fontstack}{range}",
```

Comment: Hey! I have a question regarding the path /data/myfonts.pbf
How does the path look locally for you? What is your folder structure?

Comment: @WalterMonecke "data" is a subfolder in the website that contains "0-255.pbf". So glyphs is a URL to that file wherever it is in your site, I used a relative path but I think an absolute path would be fine also

Answer (score 2):

A super simple way for **Glyph file generation** is to go here: https://maplibre.org/font-maker/ and upload your font, then download the zip.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).